# Pandoc : generate a html embedding Latex equation from markdown input

Tags: html, latex, markdown, pandoc

I am trying to convert a markdown file containing a Latex equation to an Html file using pandoc.

I tried the following synthax in file `test.md` :

```
$$ \frac{1}{2} = 0.5 \neq \sqrt{2} $$
```

and I invoked pandoc using

```
pandoc test.md -o test.html --mathjax
```

as seems to be indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25065430/3492512). The generated `test.html` file contains the single line

```
<p><span class="math">\[ \frac{1}{2} = 0.5 \neq \sqrt{2} \]</span></p>
```

and when opening `test.html` with a web browser, the output on the screen is litteraly

```
\[ \frac{1}{2} = 0.5 \neq \sqrt{2} \]
```

instead of a nice "latex-compiled" equation.

What did I miss?

P.S. I am using pandoc 1.12.2.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `test.html` file generated was not "complete" in the sense that only the body of the html was generated, and not the header. However, mathjax must be linked in the header for the equation to be displayed nicely.

To generate a "complete" html file with the `<html>` `<head>` and `<body>` tags, pandoc's `--standalone` (aka `-s`) option must be used

```
pandoc --standalone test.md -o test.html --mathjax
```

---

## More details

Using the invocation

```
pandoc --standalone test.md -o test.html --mathjax
```

generates the following `test.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>
    <script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><span class="math">\[ \frac{1}{2} = 0.5 \neq \sqrt{2} \]</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

(note the `<script>` tag linking to mathjax in the `<head>` section)
whereas the invocation

```
pandoc test.md -o test.html --mathjax
```

generates a file containing merely a single-line

```
<p><span class="math">\[ \frac{1}{2} = 0.5 \neq \sqrt{2} \]</span></p>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.